# Make a list of most used keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with these columns: id, text, keywords.

ID is an id. Text is a title. Keywords is a list of tags in this format: `tag1 tag2 tag3`.

How would I go about getting a list of the most used keywords in the column? Eg. if I wanted to build a tag cloud from all the items in the table.

Comment: Are you stuck with this format or can you say, normalize your data?

Comment: Hi Mark, I can change the format. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Your additional comment below would be best addressed as a new question. Check out my response below, and create a new question. This question (if it has been addressed) should be marked with an accepted answer to show it has been answered.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to do what you want. But it won't be simple. The way you have organized your keywords in this database is going to cause quite a few headaches. You should try to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data.

Perhaps instead of this:

```
id   text   keywords
1    bob    he she it
2    thing  white yellow hello
```

Have an separate table for the keywords:

```
id keyword
1  he
1  she
2  white
2  yellow
```

That way, it would be a much simpler matter to find what you want:

```
select count(keyword) as num from `keywords` group by keyword order by num desc
```

Comment: New problem: when I want to enter tags in my database, before I just had a text field with space separated tags, ready to go into the db.

Now I must make a query for each tag I want to add each item?

Comment: It would be best to create a new question for this so that more people see it and keep this one marked as answered (by selecting an 'accepted answer'). Comment here with a link to the question and I'll take a look.

Comment: @John: Each tag you add will need to be entered one at a time, so you'll have one UPDATE query for each. You can set this up fairly cleanly in a form for entry, though. Or perhaps your form handling code could split the entry by spaces and do separate queries. The hassle at the front end is certainly worth the normalization at the back end.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create an array where each key is `tag#`. The value of each of those keys is the number of times `tag#` appears in the database; this would involve traversing through each tag in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off normalising your database tables.  Maybe something like this:

```
Items table :  id, text

Tags table : id, text

items_tags table:  item_id, tag_id
```

This way you can associate multiple tags with each item, and queries for tag counts become easy.